# Powershell Script to Pull Various Data Fields in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

This is what I currently have to pull a specific facility list of all departments.  What I now need to discover is the various Job Titles they have for this facility, the tricky part is that the Titles are not listed within the attributes for the user accounts within active directory.  The titles are only listed under  Organization tab -> Job Title.  Simply adding "title" into the code does not work since that field is left blank where the script is trying to pull it from, I just need to redirect it to pull from the Job Title field under the Organization tab.

```
Get-ADUSER -LDAPFilter "(extensionattribute7=)"-properties department | select-object name,department -unique |  Sort-object department | 
Select Department -unique | Export-Csv -NoType MyCSVfile.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `Title` to the `-Properties` parameter, it will be returned by `Get-ADUser`. But if your `Select-Object` statements don't include it, it will be discarded.

You may want to do this in multiple statements instead of a single pipeline.

```
$users = Get-ADUSER -LDAPFilter "(extensionattribute7=)"-properties department,title
$depts = $users | Select-Object Department -Unique
$titles = $users | Select-Object Title -Unique
```